# How to get records count into a access form's text box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a access table that I am doing a search by date range on. In the form I have a text box TxtTotal that I want to display the number of records in the  filtered range the code I have. keeps giving me the complete number of records and not the range filtered.

This is my module

```
Function FindRecordCount(strSQL As String) As Long
     Dim db As Database
     Dim rstRecords As Recordset

'On error GoTo ErrorHandler
            Set db = CurrentDb
            Set rstRecords = db.OpenRecordset("TblPurchases")
    If rstRecords.EOF Then
    FindRecordCount = 0
Else
    rstRecords.MoveLast
    FindRecordCount = rstRecords.RecordCount

End If
   rstRecords.Close
   db.Close
Set rstRecords = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

This is my code for the TxtTotal text box on the form

```
   Sub Search()
   Dim strCriteria, task As String

      Me.Refresh
     If IsNull(Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom) Or IsNull(Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo) 
 Then
   MsgBox "Please enter the date range", vbInformation, "Date Range 
   Required"
    Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom.SetFocus
  Else
    strCriteria = "([Date of Purchase] >= #" & Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom & 
   "# and [Date of Purchase] <= #" & Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo & "#)"
    task = "select * from TblPurchases where( " & strCriteria & ") order 
    by [Date of Purchase] "
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
    Me.TxtTotal = FindRecordCount(task)
End If
```

End Sub

the results keeps giving me the complete number of records and not the range filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue is this line:

```
Set rstRecords = db.OpenRecordset("TblPurchases")
```

You are setting the Record set to use the table as its source instead of your SQL string. No matter what your input dates are, if you are looking at the whole table, it will return the whole table xD.

As for finding the total count of items from a query result, it might make sense to use the SQL COUNT function eg: `SELECT COUNT(<Column>) FROM <table> WHERE <criteria>;` This will provide you the number of data entries that are provided from that query.

I would also recommend using the QueryDef Object for your SQL definitions since it makes things a little cleaner. But again, this is just a recommendation EG:

```
Function FindRecordCount(dateFrom As Date, dateTo As Date) As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim QDF As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rstRecords As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TblPurchase WHERE([Date of Purchase] >= #@dateFrom# AND [Date of Purchase] <= #@dateTo#)"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set QDF = db.QuerDefs(SQL)
    QDF.Paramaters("@dateFrom").Value = dateFrom
    QDF.Paramaters("@dateTo").Value = dateTo

    Set rstRecords = QDF.OpenRecordset("TblPurchases")

    If rstRecords.EOF Then
        FindRecordCount = 0
    Else
        rstRecords.MoveLast
        FindRecordCount = rstRecords.RecordCount
    End If

    rstRecords.Close
    QDF.Close
    db.Close
    Set rstRecords = Nothing
    Set QDF = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and recommendation, I'm really green to access so please excuse my dumb questions, I will study and work on your recommendations Thanks.

Comment: No problem, You always start somewhere right? xD If that works let me know I am interested since I have never actually really worked with access Dates (I always convert to the UNIX timestamp (information here: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

Comment: Hi Eli, I got the date issue resolved , thanks. I was wondering if it is possible to use the same search button control to also perform a additional search that will give me the results of a particular field along with the date range? ie I get the range of dates then the results of say the vendors used within that date range and or selected vendors, or will I have to use a separate search button just for the vendors.my goal is to be able to filter the records by vendors thats one search the at the same time while having the vendors filtered filter for items purchased.  any resources you know .

Comment: Will you be using the same search criteria (the date start and end) or be adding new criteria? If you are just adding new criteria the same button should work, just add more filter criteria in the vba code. (not sure if that answers your question or not)

Comment: yes I will be using t he same search criteria .I tried this too, I listed the vendors in the combo box and tried a vba code to filter the records

    Private sub cboVendors_AfterUpdate()
  Me.Filter= "[Vendors] = " & char(34) & Me.cboVendors & char(34)
  Me.FilterOn =True

  End Sub


  
I'm using Access 2016 and get a compile error
   Sub or function not defined
If I dim chae(34)
I get a syntax error(missingOperator) in query expression[vendors] = Ace Hardware

 the vendor selected
the code I used I found on a Youtube video online that seemed to work with Access 2007

Comment: It might be a good idea to open another question on this matter. Once you do so let me know the link so I can review it. I will take this info that you gave me and see if I can figure out something as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for the help I actually got this suggestion from the community which I tried and it        works       Me.TxtTotal = Format(DCount("vendor", "TblPurchases Query"), "0") I dropped two of the zeros to keep it from placing  zeros ahead of the count, but thanks for all your help I'm currently struggling with another issue you can see from my post, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all this with a *DCount* expression in the *ControlSource* of the textbox `txtTotal`:

```
=DCount("*","TblPurchase ","[Date of Purchase] Between #" & Format(Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateFrom.Value,Date()), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateTo.Value,Date()), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```